# Best way to find longest common suffix of two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given two arrays, I need to find the longest common suffix.

More precisely, I need to find the index in each array, after which that suffix appears.

For example:

```
// Input
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
arr2 = [11,12,13,5,6];

// Output
ind1 = 4;
ind2 = 3;
```

Here is my code:

```
let ind1 = arr1.length - 1;
let ind2 = arr2.length - 1;
while (ind1 >= 0 && ind2 >= 0 && arr1[ind1] == arr2[ind2]) {
    ind1--;
    ind2--;
}
ind1++;
ind2++;
```

Is there a single-statement trick (or a "cleaner" way in general) that I can apply here instead?

Comment: please add the arrays and the wanted result.

Comment: I have read a similar question few days ago. I'll try if I can find the link.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Done, thank you.

Comment: both the arrays have equal length always?

Comment: @talentedandrew: No (look at the example).

Comment: What if arrays are like: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,6,5,4,7,8,9]`?

Comment: @Rajesh: Try the code. It should give you `ind1 = 0` and `ind2 = 0`.

Comment: @goodvibration *I need to find the longest common suffix*, so longest suffix is `7,8,9` and not `1,2`

Comment: @Rajesh: Oh, sorry, I thought they were identical in your example. Yes, the suffix here is `7,8,9`, so the output should be `ind1 = 6` and `ind2 = 5`.

Comment: @goodvibration I have added an answer based on our above discussion. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a *single-statement trick* or *cleaner* approach, but it essentially does a lot more than your existing code.

As per discussion:

> What if arrays are like: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,6,5,4,7,8,9]? – **Rajesh**
>
> @Rajesh: Try the code. It should give you ind1 = 0 and ind2 = 0. – **goodvibration**
>
> @goodvibration I need to find the longest common suffix, so longest suffix is 7,8,9 and not 1,2 – **Rajesh**
>
> Oh, sorry, I thought they were identical in your example. Yes, the suffix here is 7,8,9, so the output should be ind1 = 6 and ind2 = 5. – **goodvibration**

you are looking for a logic that returns starting index of largest sequence. For this you will have to capture all the sequences and check for their length before returning the indexes.

You can try following logic:

- Create a temporary object that will hold positions.
- Now loop over array.

  - If the start position for Array1 is undefined, look for index of matching element.
  - Save this indexes in temp object and continue.
  - If startPosition is defined, look for next value in both array to be equal.
  - If equal, continue.
  - If not, create a group and start the process again from this index.

```js
function getLongestSuffixIndex(a1, a2) {
  var temp = {}
  var groups = [];
  var lastA2Index = 0;
  var a2Index = -1;
  var part;

  function addGroup() {
    if (temp.startA1Index !== undefined) {
      groups.push({
        a1Index: temp.startA1Index,
        a2Index: temp.startA2Index,
        count: temp.endA1Index - temp.startA1Index + 1
      });
      temp = {};
    }
  }

  function checkForIndex(i) {
    a2Index = part.indexOf(a1[i]);
    if (a2Index >= 0) {
      temp.startA1Index = i;
      temp.startA2Index = a2Index + lastA2Index;
      lastA2Index += a2Index;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0, len = a1.length; i < len; i++) {
    part = a2.slice(lastA2Index);
    if (temp.startA1Index === undefined) {
      checkForIndex(i);
    } else {
      var index = (temp.startA2Index || 0) + (temp.count|| 0) + 1
      if (a1[i] === a2[index]) {
        temp.endA1Index = i;
        temp.count = i - temp.startA1Index;
      } else {
        addGroup();
        checkForIndex(i);
      }
    }
  }
  addGroup();

  return groups.length ? groups.reduce(function(p, c) {
    return ((p.count || 0) > (c.count || 0)) ? p : c
  }) : undefined;
}

var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var arr2 = [11, 12, 13, 5, 6];

console.log(getLongestSuffixIndex(arr1, arr2))
console.log(getLongestSuffixIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Comment: "you are looking for a logic that returns starting index of largest sequence" - what exactly do you mean by "largest sequence"? Doesn't sound quite like what I'm looking for.

Comment: It means *the longest common suffix*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single variable for counting up from the end of the arrays.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    array2 = [11, 12, 13, 5, 6],
    l1 = array1.length - 1,
    l2 = array2.length - 1,
    i = 0;
    
while (i <= l1 && i <= l2 && array1[l1 - i] === array2[l2 - i]) {
    i++;
}

console.log('index array1', l1 - i + 1);
console.log('index array2', l2 - i + 1);
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants this output, but then I don't even understand the real problem.

Comment: This code is not "cleaner" in any way comparing to what I already have, and in addition, not safe (exception on empty arrays)

Comment: it returns the common elements from the end of both arrays (as i have understood the question ...).

Comment: No, I need an index (one for each array) telling me where the common elements start.

Comment: `===` is deep comparison??? Wow, thanks man!!! Just gave me an unrelated but vital piece of information!

Comment: who is saying deep comparison?

Comment: @NinaScholz Please read the my last 2 comments under question. It changes the requirement and makes your answer void

Comment: @Rajesh: The question hasn't changed, regardless of your comments (maybe your understanding of the question has).

Comment: i actually do not understand the problem with this answer.

Comment: @NinaScholz: No problem. The code works correctly, it's just not cleaner or simpler in any manner comparing to what I already have (at least as far as I can see). So it doesn't really address my requirement. But thank you regardless.

Comment: @goodvibration, it takes only one variable for counting, but you need still to check the bounds.

Comment: Yes, but on the other hand it also uses an additional variable.

Answer (score 0):

`~ind1` can be used instead of `ind1 >= 0` as short for `ind1 != -1`:

```
while (~ind1 && ~ind2 && arr1[ind1] == arr2[ind2]) { ind1--; ind2--; }
```

The decrements can be moved to avoid the `.length - 1` (`&` is needed to do both decrements):

```
var i = arr1.length, j = arr2.length; while (~--i & ~--j && arr1[i] == arr2[j]) { }
```

For numeric values the condition can be even shorter, because `undefined - undefined` is `NaN`:

```
while (arr1[--i] - arr2[--j] == 0) { }
```

---

I put each on one line to compare with the original, so sorry about the mess ..

```js
for ([a, b] of [ [[1,2,3,4], [1,'3',4]], [[1], [0,1]], [[], []], [[,], [0]] ]) 
{
  var i = a.length - 1; var j = b.length - 1; while (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && a[i] == b[j]) { i--; j--; } i++; j++; console.log(i, j, a.length - i)   /* original version */

  var i = a.length, j = b.length; while (~--i & ~--j && a[i] == b[j]) { } i++; j++; console.log(i, j, a.length - i)   /* ~--i is short for (i = i - 1) != -1 */

  var i = a.length, j = b.length; while (a[--i] - b[--j] == 0) { } i++; j++; console.log(i, j, a.length - i)   /* a bit shorter, but minus works only with values convertible to Number */
}
```

As a side note, I would expect a common suffix function to return a string or number of characters.